# Русскоязычные символы в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, кодировка

Стандартный код для создания сервера Node.js и вывода сообщения в браузер искажает русский текст. Вместо "Привет!" выдает крокозябры. Как быть? Пишу в notepad++, там выставлена кодировка UTF-8 без BOM, в командной строке русский текст отображается как положено.

```
const http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request,response){

    response.end("Привет!");

}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1",function(){
    console.log("Сервер начал прослушивание запросов на порту 3000");
});
```

Comment: *А какой charset вы в заголовке `Content-Type` указали?*

Comment: У меня нет файла с метатегами, есть только app.js с данным кодом

Comment: Ну так посмотрите какой заголовок отсылается браузеру в инструментах разработчика! Кстати, причём тут файл с метатегами?

Comment: Имею в виду <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" сharset="utf-8">

Comment: При чём тут вообще тэг meta, если вы строку отсылаете, а не HTML? Проверьте заголовок.

Comment: Это я нашел, а на что конкретно там нужно обратить внимание?

Comment: На параметр charset

Comment: И хром, и файрфокс в заголовках ответа выдают только 3 пункта: Connection, Content-Length и Date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37033450/4496422

Comment: @nörbörnën - работает, благодарю вас. Получается, недостаточно вывести сообщение, нужно также задавать дополнительные параметры вывода?

Comment: @Yuri это не дополнительные параметры, а обязательные

Comment: @nörbörnën, теперь понял